# Scalable POJO remote service to internal Java clients without RMI

Tags: java, rmi, pojo, apache-mina

I want to expose POJO as highly scalable remote services to be used by other internal Java clients without using RMI or any application server dependency. Spring has support to expose POJO as remote services (Hessian/Burlap), but using HTTP/JMS. I am looking for some framework that uses plain sockets communication via TCP/IP.

Is there something that uses NIO to make synchronize calls with automatic failover?

This one looks promising http://code.google.com/p/mina-spring/

Answer (score 0):

Spring also provides support to expose POJO's over RMI. I don't think you can find anything that supports simple TCP/IP sockets (using NIO or blocking IO) as the protocol itself will be tightly coupled with the objects you pass in between and the order they are passed in (e.g. a function with 1 parameter will only need a serialized object passed through whereas a function with 2 parameters will need 2 objects, and the order will be important etc).